# Errors with starting Runescape

Tags: runescape

When I try to start Runescape I get an error message that says: CLassNotFoundException and lists Rs2Applet.class. How do I fix this so I can play?

Comment: Was any effort made to attempt to resolve this on your own before asking here?

Comment: @fbueckert Um yeah. I wouldn't be asking random questions just for the fun of it.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Except that when I did a google search for "runescape classnotfoundexception" the *very first* result was Jagex's support page detailing your exact problem and a solution. We ask users to show at least a *little* effort to solve a problem on their own before asking a question.

Comment: @SaintWacko I would have copy-pasted the contents here if I were you. ;)

Comment: @Mugen The answer already did so, so I didn't bother. Although I did consider linking to lmgtfy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Your firewall blocks Java from downloading the RuneScape applet. Try configuring the firewall to allow Java. As some firewalls cause problems specifically with Java 7, downgrading to Java 6 may help.

Source: [Jagex Support Page](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Community_-_Tech_Support/Solutions#ClassNotFoundException_.28RS2Applet.class.29)

Comment: How do I get rid of my new java and get the older one?

Comment: @YoungGuilo [Are you](http://www.java.com/en/download/uninstall.jsp) [on Windows?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html)

Answer (score 0):

Disable any proxies or proxy add ons you might have.Had the same issue and disabling the data compression proxy addon in chrome did the trick.